# Generating skew-normal distribution in Matlab

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, matlab, random-generation, skew-normal-distribution

My apologies if this is a trivial question, but I am having trouble with this for a while now.

I need to use a skew-normal distribution in research in MATLAB and the only way I found after googling was to use Pearsrnd, as given in [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/314884-how-can-i-generate-skewed-normal-random-numbers.).

Now, I did the math  and wrote function skewnormal function in MATLAB as follows:

```
    %% The helper function calculating parameters for skew-normal using pearsrnd
function [m,s, sk, kurt] = skewnormal(a, e, w)
    c = sqrt(2/pi); % it is used a lot in what follows
    d = a/sqrt(1+a*a); % temp variable
    m = e + d*w*c; % mean 
    s = w*sqrt(1 - d^2*c^2); % variance
    sk = (4 - pi)/2*(d*c*w/s)^3; % skewness
    kurt = 3 + 2*(pi-3)*(d*c*w/s)^4; % kurtosis accounted for the matlab convention.
end
```

Then, when I use the above in my code and return the type of the Pearsrnd, it returns $1$ - which is apparently Four parameters Beta distribution in Pearsrnd.

I did look for answers here that could immediately answer but I did not find any.

Can anyone fix my attempt at generating Skew-Normal distribution, since I am clearly doing something wrong?

Comment: If the question is just how to use `pearsrnd` just drop an e-mail to MathWorks support. These are pretty much bread and butter for them.

Comment: @dezdichado does the answer I've provided give you what you were looking for or is there additional context not in the OP? Reason I ask is b/c my answer hasn't been marked correct and we're coming up on the end of bounty period, see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/bounty for policies on bounties. If I've missed something please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the following approach: 
First you need the command to generate a "standard normal", e.g. N(0,1)

https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normrnd.html

then given 2 random normals, you can use the following formula:

$$
Y = \mu + \sigma \left(\delta|T_0| + T_1\sqrt{1-\delta^2}\right),
$$where

$$
\delta = \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{1+\lambda^2}}
$$
from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251696468_Skew_scale_mixtures_of_normal_distributions_Properties_and_estimation/related), where $T_0,T_1$ are both standard normal random variates. 
Also, the values $\mu, \sigma, \lambda$ are parameters/arguments to the function so I assume those 3 parameters are given.

In code this looks something like:

```
t0 = normrnd(0,1)
t1 = normrnd(0,1)
d  = _lambda / sqrt(1 + _lambda*_lambda)
y  = mu + sigma * (d * abs(t0) + t1 * sqrt(1 - d * d))
```

Of course, if you want to you can wrap that into a function in matlab. I don't really know matlab so if the syntax isn't the greatest, please adjust accordingly. Hopefully, the logical calculations are simple enough that you can modify appropriately for your uses.

EDIT: The $\delta$ or equivalently, the $\lambda$ is the parameter that determines the extent and nature (positive or negative) of the skew.